# Getting & storing large amounts of data

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, memory

I'm tasked with pulling down a significant amount of information from our database for a website, up to 40MB. I'm concerned with pulling down so much data, and storing it in variables, because I don't want to run into any out of memory exceptions. What I'm considering doing is pulling down the records 1 or 2 thousand at at time, then appending them to the CSV file for the user to download after all records are processed. So at no point there is an object containing more than a MB or so.

My question is, if I use File.AppendText to keep adding to the file, does it store the entire CSV file in memory before adding it to the end?

Comment: A text-file of that size is pretty common. 40MB isn´t really much and shouldn´t avoid any memory-problems. However I don´t really get your question. You dowbload a text-file and append some text to it. What´s the problem? `AppendToText` will surely write directly to the file

Comment: *"if I use File.AppendText to keep adding to the file, does it store the entire CSV file in memory before adding it to the end"* No, it does not work like that. It will not read the entire file into memory then add the text and write it back out.

Comment: Your data is 40M and you want to avoid OOM execptions. What much RAM do you have?

Comment: @Eser:  RAM is irrelevant to running out of memory. OOM is running out of *virtual address space*, not *RAM*.  RAM is not address space and has not been for many decades.  When your working set exceeds available RAM your machine gets *slow*, it does not OOM.

Comment: Solve problems you actually have. You have an 8 trillion byte address space on a 64 bit windows machine and you are worried about 40 million bytes. This is rather like being a billionaire and worrying about running out of money when you buy gum.

Comment: If you are worried about memory usage then **use science to inform yourself of empirical reality**.  Write the code, get a memory profiler, and see how much memory you are using.